# What kind of headphone is best in a noisy bus?

Tags: headphones

What is the best ear-bud headphones that would best isolate outside noise so I don't have to turn up my headphones that is around or less than $50? (Noise-canceling, noise-isolating, etc)

Comment: Not computer related.  It might have stood a chance if it was connected to a computer but we have a few of those already, like http://superuser.com/questions/29095/what-are-good-noise-reducing-earphones-for-use-with-a-pc

Comment: http://www.head-fi.org/forums/ might be better equipped to answer you, but be careful about using the word "best" with them.  Hi-end audio can get ridiculous price-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Etymotics - hands down.

Web site [here](http://www.etymotic.com/Default.aspx)

You are probably looking at the Isolator line [here](http://www.etymotic.com/ephp/er6i.aspx) - more the fifty bucks though.

Though you can use the Etymotics noise isolator fittings on other brands of ear buds - take a look for "etymotic hybrid" on Ebay, a random example [here](http://cgi.ebay.com/Koss-the-Plug-Etymotic-ER4-Noise-Isolation-tip-hybrid_W0QQitemZ250497273979QQcmdZViewItemQQptZLH_DefaultDomain_0?hash=item3a52cd107b&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14) - Less than fifty bucks.

(I am going have to figure out how to get images into these responses - sorry)

Answer (score 0):

i can only recommend **[Acoustibuds](http://www.acoustibuds.com/)**

> The flexible fins create multiple
>   reflective sound barriers for superior
>   sound isolation while they hold the
>   earphone securely in position. This
>   gives a big boost in bass and
>   conserves sound energy so your MP3 can
>   be played at lower volumes while
>   **blocking outside noise**.

... and well within your budget.

Comment: Do you own it? How do you like it? Pro/cons?

Comment: i do and i like :) pro: does what it says on the tin, using them with my Cowon S9, stock earbuds, excellent sound quality got even better and background noise is greatly reduced. Cons a bit pricey, you might get some clones cheaper, but i couldn't vouch for the quality.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many earphones, cheap and not cheap, including Shure, Etymotic, Sony, etc. They all underperformed.

That is until I bought Ultimate Ears Super Fi 5. It's above your budget, but considering I've had the same pair for 3 years now and they took care of all cord/bud wear problems at no charge, they're well worth it. I wrote a more detailed review [here](http://beerpla.net/2006/09/18/review-of-ultimate-ears-superfi-5-pro-earphones/).

Seriously, don't knock it till you try them. Best earphones I've ever owned.

[image]

Comment: i think, 250 bucks is a bit off the rocker :)

Comment: They look nice, but as Molly said, quite expensive ;)

Comment: Considering they come with a detachable cord, they'll pretty much last a lifetime. The cord rips - just ask them for a new one. It's quite sturdy though already.